# Database queries for an assignment

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a project and I am a newbie in database. I need help answering the questions below with the scenario and the database tables listed.

Database tables:

- `Product` (pid:integer, timestamp:integer, name: string, price:real, location:string)
- `Customer` (cid:integer, email: string)
- `Purchases` (pid:integer, cid:integer, orderid:integer, amount:integer)
- `Totals` (orderid:integer, cid:integer, totalprice:real, timestamp:integer)

**Scenario:**

A product ID can occur multiple times in the schema. Each time the location or price is updated, another line is added to the database with a timestamp that indicates the time of change. The name does not get changed, so the same pid will always imply the same name.

Totals is a summary of the purchases table which shows when the purchases were made, and what the combined price of all products were.

Whenever possible, try to do your projections as early as possible.

Use the above database and provide queries for the following problems:

1. Find the names of products that at some point in time cost more than e20.00 and the names of products that have at some point cost less than e0.10.
2. Find the email addresses of customers that have spent more than e200 at once.
3. Find the pids of products that have had at least one price change.
4. Find the names of products that have both been displayed at location ’5-12’ and ’A3’
5. Find the cid of customers that have bought each product that at some point cost less than e1.00
6. Find the cid of customers that are registered with the store but have made no purchases.
7. Find the cid of the customer(s) that have made the largest total purchase.
8. Find the most expensive product that has been purchased at least once by each registered customer.
9. Find the pids of products that have not been sold since timestamp 20150625 but have been sold at least once before that date.
10. The grocery store wants to improve its database. Write a query that returns a table that is basically the Purchases table plus the price of the product at the time of purchase.

Comment: We will not do your homework, you have to learn and try it by yourself, and if you really don't undestand something then you should do a specific question about it, but not as general as "do my homework."

Comment: Hi Criw, this is not a home work. This is a project I am working on. I have already created the database and the tables, I tried running the queries but I keep getting no results. Please can you give me an idea for the first query, that will actually help me in the task.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to provide you a bit of help to start your project ❤

In query one, we need to work exclusively with table `Products`, and You want to find the `name` of those products with `price` above x and less than y.

First, the columns we want to get FROM the table:

```
SELECT name, price FROM Products
```

Then, as you need a query that get products more expensive than `20`, and producs less expensive than `0.10`, you could use the Condition [BETWEEN](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and.php) reverted with [NOT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html):

```
SELECT name, price FROM Products
WHERE price NOT BETWEEN 0.10 and 20
```

And you can order it to be more readable:

```
SELECT name, price FROM Products
WHERE price NOT BETWEEN 0.10 and 20
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but I hope it helps a bit!